# Can't decode base64 php string

Tags: php, base64, decode

I'm trying to decode php code which is encoded with base64. i tried a lot of decoders but many of them gives me such code after decoding:

```
<?php goto Feb9e43796f9f57d45a8f7; a8f31548518d03e36c707c: Ef4e1fa42dfe9253ba883e: goto E7a3d7286987dad23ead3a; a675cc71ff9ce0bc969a58: goto C5782de7f7be908d2240f9; goto a70b4de94912343b68ec50; E8807e5956a415b0e7f5c4: goto b10784ba5d102329c346aa; goto B1cb89b557708d13481bbb; Aa08ed5ce5a887c0cee761: goto cc14d421fd2d5512a37531; goto B32f058374ecdd9eff6ddf; e04f4774b9b39565ea6d44: a26d201b375335c024a324: goto F7a1d2cb15e9bace7570fc; b09ad940d5d66994116a40: goto bad075430d16ee8df9835b; goto B6c3948b6fe0b9147d2292; D1bf5e026df4c3c4a93b8e: f899a4b412db88142946f4: goto ef5c70d5c8563f7e852b02; F5da1098834d3300373c86: goto e79df90821495ddb30cb12; goto E8a5bd2f9799f71828ec61; dcae2dc69713039e757fe5: goto a6c076ba843af1cda3a381; goto Aa2e0fd49457ab79bf395b; c3d35b0313aca4c099bccd: a7f54900a6c2d74464dd04: goto e5931eb22b5f53596fe630; e4974776b3f31fd0c9f708: goto a48a6d01b8a965d16fdf5f; goto f2f8706e254b6976e4edf7; Fe73b5ecef06d2d3192dba: goto fb815d94c852f723dac171; goto c17686c2d9123babd0c719; f1a18d03b14b27b96ae1fe: d9db5a9e767a9188b96f53: goto c0827189645756b73ac658; b5bd3be2562a2fcb313298: goto B8f0f0f0eefbd2d84fdc07; goto C4fbf4c2cd9f8b065cc153; Bd0f5e30de3222dd4e35fc: A7b0b6880cd409ea63c118: goto E41f1e47b7e40b209f5dde; cb6cb4ecd4a82b3e23f865: goto e69752e9d99588ab19c0f1; goto E5990dceb5b6c1b95fe65c; Ce19ba4aaea45c04da1615: goto b6bb7fef0e62497c3d8a2f; goto C2bf113d50280a2dce98fa;
```

And so on the whole code... (it is very large)

I noticed only different part in this decoded code and it is:

```
if (!(Ae8eee096B7B4A965cD0c9($_GET["\157\160"], $_GET["\143\x6c\x69\x65\x6e\x74"], $ccd718bd0bf898ad2f0345, $_GET["\x74\x72\x61\x6e\x73\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\156\x5f\151\144"]) != $_GET["\150\141\x73\x68"])) { goto d5b8787e1efa414d3fe2b5; } goto Aad0584a58098d9da3ac10; Fd53511cab6836a17661e3: e5c79ec71eaf01988cdd00: goto Ee8f202cbf6deb5a4f62cf;
```

How can I decode it properly to see what code is it exactly?

Comment: That's normal code; there's nothing to "decode" (except string literals).  It just uses ugly names.

Comment: but the whole code it just continues and nothing more

Comment: Decoders can't make unintelligible code understandable.

Comment: They look like unique id's, not base64 encoded strings. ive tried to decode but did not work.